# How to post message to slack channel\user using Signing Secret and python requests

Tags: python-requests, slack-api

Lately Slack API recommend using Signing Secrets - but I can't find in the documentation a proper explanation how to post a message with rest api.

Is there a good example \ proper documentation or even better - a code sample of posting a message to channel using Python Requests + Signing Secret?
(Or any other language\lib + Signing Secret).

Answer (score 1):

Signing Secret isn't necessary in every situation.
If you are sending massage to channel you don't need to use signing key.
As documentation said Signing Secret is used when you are receiving information from Slack.

> What are signed secrets?
> Slack creates a unique string for your app and shares it with you.
> Verify requests from Slack with confidence by verifying signatures
> using your signing secret.

Grate examples with usage of Signing Secret you can find at their github:
[With socket usage](https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/blob/main/examples/socket_mode_oauth.py)
[With flask server usage](https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/blob/main/examples/app_authorize.py)

But TL;DR everything what you have to do is pass secret while you are creating  App object.
Something like this:

```
app = App(signing_secret=os.environ["SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET"], authorize=authorize)
```

Implementation of request verification in Python Bolt framework:
https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/tree/main/slack_bolt/middleware/request_verification